# How to update the particular row in Listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, adapter

I have implemented list view which scroll vertically, in each row there is a items like apple, lemon etc those items are scroll horizontally. Now my problem is i need to sort the items in selected row and i need to update the result to that row here i am not able to update the values to particular row.First time i am loading a data from activity to adapter and sorted values i am loading in adapter class.

Here code is..

```
public static ArrayList<GroupsModel> CustomListViewValuesArr;
        public static ArrayList<ItemsModel> ItemsArr;

        public MyDisplay_Adapter(Context a, ArrayList d) {

            context = a;
            data = d;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            if (data.size() <= 0)
                return 1;
            return data.size();
        }

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {

            public TextView tvGroupTitle, tvGroupDescription, 
            public LinearLayout imgscrollchild;

        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.d("getview:", "position=" + position);
            vi = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_asset_list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tvGroupTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupTitle);

                holder.tvGroupDescription = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvGroupDescription);
                holder.imgscrollchild = (LinearLayout) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgscrollchild);

                vi.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

            }
            if (data.size() <= 0) {

                vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                tempValues = null;
                tempValues = (GroupsModel) data.get(position);

                holder.tvGroupTitle.setText(tempValues.getName().toString());
                holder.tvGroupDescription.setText(tempValues.getDescription()
                        .toString());


                if (tempValues.getItemmodel().size() == 0) {

                    return vi;

                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempValues.getItemmodel().size(); i++) {

                        a = i;
                        Log.i("Index", String.valueOf(i));
                        holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(
                                tempValues.getItemmodel(), a));
                        Log.i("Index A", String.valueOf(a));

                    }
                }

            }
            return vi;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public View createimg(final List<ItemsModel> bm, final int pos) {

            Here dynamically creating a imageview and textview


            return Hlayout;

        }



        private class Sort extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String json = null;

                try {

                    String url_get = "my url"

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url_get);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        try {

                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
                            ItemsArr = new ArrayList<ItemsModel>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject Obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                String GName = Obj.getString("GName");
                                String GDesc = Obj.getString("GDesc");

                                ItemsArr.add(ItemsList);

                            }

                            GroupsModel list1 = new GroupsModel();
                            list1.setItemmodel(ItemsArr);
                            CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<GroupsModel>();
                            CustomListViewValuesArr.add(list1);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                adapter = new MyDisplay_Adapter(context,CustomListViewValuesArr);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Here code is..` Unclear what you're asking is.

Comment: I need to sort the items and update the sorted values to particular row in custom adapter

Comment: I am confusing how to update the values to adapter in adapter class only

Comment: `I need to sort the items` So, simply retrieve them sorted.

Comment: i am getting sorted value but i am  confusing how to update it to particular row

Comment: On which criteria you want to sort list?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a new adapter instance on postExecute of your async task. You sholud create a method to change data on your adapter instead. And call it on PostExecute like:

```
    adapter.setData(myData);

    adaptar.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

If you don't want to do it like this and if you need to recreate an adapter you should reset it like:

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note: Code examples may be different from exact code.

Answer (score 0):

update the updated objects to the arraylist 
you can do this either by clearing all the data from your arraylist and adding the updated data to the same list or 
you can do it by checking the objects which you want to replace
and use 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();